# NiFi data insertion into s3 subdirectory

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I have a flow where I am extracting data from the database, converting the Avro to the CSV format and pushing the CSV in an s3 bucket which has subfolder in it. My S3 structure is like the following:

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot my files are going into a blank folder(highlighted by red) instead of going inside a subfolder called 'Thermal'. Please see my PutS3Object settings:

[image]

The final s3 path I want my files to go into is: **export-csv-vehicle-telemetry/vin11/Thermal**

What settings should I change in my processor so the file goes directly inside the 'Thermal' folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bucket name as: **export-csv-vehicle-telemetry/vin15/Thermal** instead of **export-csv-vehicle-telemetry/vin15/Thermal/**

The extra slash at the end is not required while specifying bucket names.

BTW, Your image shows vin11 directory instead of vin15. Check if that is correct.